# Angular Material Table Alphanumeric Sorting Behaviour

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material

I'm having a problem in Angular Material Table, although it is technically correct, but I'm thinking if there's another way around for this.

Let say that I do have 5 codes, `F1`, `F2`, `F5`, `F9`, `F10`.

The Angular Material Table ascending sort order of this will be,

```
F1
F10
F2
F5
F9
```

But I'm expecting it to be

```
F1
F2
F5
F9
F10
```

My html code is here

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="model.financingPurposeList" class="mat-elevation-z8" width="100%">

   <ng-container matColumnDef="code">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Code </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let financingPurpose"> {{financingPurpose.code}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let financingPurpose"> {{financingPurpose.description}} </td>
   </ng-container>

   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['code', 'description']; sticky: true"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['code', 'description'];" (click)="model.selectedFinancingPurpose.toggle(row)"></tr>

</table>
```

Is there a possible way to do this?

Related Link:

[Natural Sorting](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12059)

[Sorting column containing both numbers and strings](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9966)

Comment: you should implement  a custom sort on your datasource (sortingDataAccessor). for natural order you might need to implement a custom algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't the best solution for this, but I created a short and sweet workaround for this. Using the `sort` predicate function of the `array`.

```
// Following the example to the question

financingPurposeList.sort(function(a, b){
   return a.code.length - b.code.length;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```js
var collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});
var myArray = ['F1',
'F10',
'F2',
'F5',
'F9'];
console.log(myArray.sort(collator.compare));
```

Comment: WOW. Great answer. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by adding sort function after getting the data.

**usage:**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.dataSource.data.sort((a, b) => (a.code- b.code) );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up overriding the sorting function in the data source to use local compare on two strings. The source code is here https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/table/table-data-source.ts#L165 and the relevant lines I changed are below

```js
this.dataSource.sortData = (data: T[], sort: MatSort) => {
         .
         .
         .
        let comparatorResult = 0;
        if (valueA != null && valueB != null) {
          // ----- Added this IF below ----.
          if (valueAType === 'string' && valueBType === 'string') {
            comparatorResult = (valueA as string).localeCompare(valueB as string, 'en', { numeric: true })
          } else if (valueA > valueB) {
            comparatorResult = 1;
          } else if (valueA < valueB) {
            comparatorResult = -1;
          }
        } else if (valueA != null) {
        .
        .
        .
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all place the **matSortChange** event listener that points to your sort method  into your HTML table tag. In this case its sortData($event) but the name its up to you.

```
<table mat-table matSort aria-label="Elements"  [dataSource]="dataSource" (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
```

Then in your component code add the sort method. Note that you need to insert each column name into switch statement on which you wish to sort.

```
sortData(sort: Sort): number {
const data = this.inputData.slice();
if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
  this.sortedData = data;
  return;
}

const sortedData = this.inputData.slice(); // input data is your data.
sortedData.sort((a, b) => {
  const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc'; // detect sort direction
  switch (sort.active) {
    case 'name': return this.sortAlphanumeric(a.name, b.name, isAsc); // column name
    default: return 0;
  }
});

this.dataSource.data = sortedData; // assigns sorted data to your data in the table   }
```

Next step is to add the custom natural sorting algorithm.

```
sortAlphanumeric(a: string, b: string, isAsc: boolean): number {
return isAsc ? a.localeCompare(b, 'en', { numeric: true }) : b.localeCompare(a, 'en', { numeric: true }); }
```

Similar solution with basic sort algorithm: https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview